# Unable to take screenshot of full browser page in chrome while using cucumber

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, cucumber, capybara, screenshot

I am unable to take screenshot of full web page in Chrome while using cucumber instead I am getting screenshot of webpage which is displayed on screen (without scrolling) and remaining part as black screen. But I am able to get full webpage in Firefox and IE. To my surprise screenshots are fine even in Chrome when I execute in virtual machines. All the versions are same in my local and virtual machines.

**My code for taking screenshots is:**

```
encoded_img = page.driver.browser.screenshot_as(:base64)

embed("data:image/png;base64,#{encoded_img}",'image/png')
```

I am using the below versions:

**capybara** (2.1.0)

**cucumber** (1.3.8)

**Chrome** 28.0.1500.95

**Firefox** 25.0.1

**IE8**

Answer (score 0):

i sue this command `page.save_screenshot` but you need some driver `webkit` `capybara` `poltergeist`